# IMO 2001 shortlist number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

I am reading [this IMO shortlist problem solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2001_IMO_Shortlist_Problems/N4) where it, after stating "There exists no numbers $1<m_1,m_2\leq p-2$ such that $m_1m_2\equiv1\text{ (mod }p^2\text{)}$ as $(p-2)(p-2)<p^2$ and $2^2>1$. Therefore, at most half of the values where $a_0^{p-1}\equiv 1\text{ (mod }p^2\text{)}$ are in range $1<a_0\leq p-2$.", which I understand, claims the following.

> We can again remove some of the potential values by squaring all
> $a_0\geq\sqrt{p}$ and taking their inverse. As long as no more than
> half of the values in that range can have the required property, there
> must be a pair $a$ and $a+1$ that satisfy the requirements by the
> pigeonhole principle.  $$\frac{p-\sqrt{p-2}-1}{2}\leq\frac{p-3}{2}$$

I do not understand the above derivation. Could someone please illustrate it?

Comment: There seems to be some context missing, possibly the rest of the problem. Can you post the remainder? You'll get vastly more views if people don't have to click through to a link.

Comment: @EricSnyder: I thought about your suggestion. But I feel the copying of a whole post will drown out the main message which is the quoted passage. Moreover, the whole post is but one click away.

Comment: One click away, but it means to have to look between two pages to answer. The problem is that we don't even know how the variables are defined here. Maybe you can summarize the context? (Though I did click through the link earlier and I seem to recall that it was, itself, inconsistent.)